# Landscape UIView in a Portrait Application iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, orientation

I think that the title of my question is quite clear : My application only supports a portrait device orientation. However, I'd like to display a custom view in a landscape orientation.

On android, i'd have done that with :

```
myLayout.contentOrientation=landscape; //Of course this wouldn't work but that's the idea !
```

How could I do that in iOS ?
Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT : I'd like the whole view (including content subviews) to flip as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the view is loaded, you can try to apply a rotation transformation to it:

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(90));
```

You may need before that to set the layer's anchor point, which is the point around which the view will rotate:

```
// Anchor the top right corner for example
layerView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: Great. But, as @AlfuryDB said in his answer, be careful as this transformation can be messy and may introduce glitches. If you encounter any problem with it, I'd suggest switching to his suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have applied the orientation mode to your hierarchy of views, the only allowed orientation is portrait, landscape or both if you have said that in your application configuration; all the subsequent views onwards, will work with the selected orientation/s. What you can do is to allow both : portrait and landscape, but in the event shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, check it and "dont allow" in the views you dont want to apply the orientation. The other workaround, the transform with degrees, can be messy in my experience and can add extra problems; it´s a solution yes, but in my experience, Ive had a lot of problems with that.

Comment: You're right, I was about to comment my own answer.

Comment: Thank you for those precisions !

Comment: The problem with the transformation using degrees, is you rotate the view but what about the components inside? thats the moment you realize its going to be hard to move all the components in the way you want your user interface because you are just rotating the screen, which is valid if your view hasnt a lot of complex components though.